# How to re-generate Vue component template from edited DOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am trying to build a visual editor for Vue apps where its contents can be edited interactively (things like editing static text, moving elements to other containers via drag and drop, etc). The contents are defined as a Vue template, which get rendered in the browser and then they can be edited. Is there a way to get back vue template code from the rendered DOM? Maybe the Vue objects in memory attached to DOM elements can be used for this?

As an example, I may have a Vue template like this:

```
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="container1">
    <MyComponent name="Hello" />
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <MyComponent name="World" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Which, when rendered, gets transformed into this:

```
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="container1">
    <div>Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <div>World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The user may, for instance, move one element to another container, resulting in this:

```
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="container1">
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From that, I would like to regenerate the template like this:

```
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="container1">
    <MyComponent name="Hello" />
    <MyComponent name="World" />
  </div>
</div>
```

What would be the best approach to implement something like this?
Thank you!